# Interactive plot in Python that allows real time adjustment, possible?

Tags: python

I am wondering if it's possible for Python to produce user adjustable graph, that will allow for real-time user feedback?

For example the graph below:
[line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO86T.png)

Is there any way for a user to drag point 3 up and down, after which some calculation will run and provide immediate results to the user?

If python is not the suitable tool, could you suggest an alternative?

Thank you.

Comment: How about plotly https://plot.ly/python/ ?

Comment: @FrenzyKiwi hi Kiwi, if my understanding is correct, plotly is interactive in the sense that you can mouse over the chart, and see the various values. However, I am looking for something that will allow users to input values through the chart. For example, dragging a y=x chart up by 1, and the chart will show y=x+1.

Comment: You can add various callbacks, can't guarantee that it allows for everything. If you want more, check `Dash`. Check e.g. https://community.plot.ly/t/moving-the-location-of-a-graph-point-interactively/7161 If something is not present, you can add a component yourself (with extra effort)

Comment: I'd also look at https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html, let's you provide a generator as input, and therefore, your plot will be modified based on whatever value the generator comes up with at runtime

Comment: @FrenzyKiwi  thank you so much for your help, didnt know plotly is so powerful!

Comment: Great that it helped!! Should I post it as an answer to your question?

Comment: @FrenzyKiwi Sure, please do!

Comment: @wwee Done. Sorry for the delay :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly is an excellent library, with Python bindings, that allows for creation of interactive plots. The way it works it translates e.g. Python code to JavaScript, allowing for interactive visualisation also in a browser.

Example:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np

N = 1000
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')

# or plot with: plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='basic-line')    import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np

N = 1000
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')

# or plot with: plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='basic-line')
```

Plotly has a paid subscription that allows for private plots stored on Plotly site. If you don't need this feature, you can happily use the free version.